# Only adding elements to the right side of the tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, postorder

On Leetcode, I'm supposed to "flatten" a tree so that it becomes a "linked list."

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode() {}
 *     TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
 *         this.val = val;
 *         this.left = left;
 *         this.right = right;
 *     }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    TreeNode result =  new TreeNode(-1);;
    
    public void flatten(TreeNode root) {
        if (root == null) return; 
        solution1(root);
        root = result.right; 
    }
    
    public void solution1(TreeNode root) {
        if (root != null) {
            
            result.right = new TreeNode(root.val);
            result = result.right;
            

            if (root.left != null) solution1(root.left);
            if (root.right != null) solution1(root.right);
        }
    }
}
```

The problematic lines of code is here:

```
result.right = new TreeNode(root.val);
result = result.right;
```

I'm trying to only add elements to the right side of the tree (so it looks like a linked list) but every time when I run my code, my "linked list" looks like an exact copy of the inputted tree.

If anyone could point me towards the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it!

https://leetcode.com/problems/flatten-binary-tree-to-linked-list/
^ that's the problem. The code I posted is my first "rundown" of what I think a naive solution might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of `result = result.right;` your `result` points to the last node you added.
So there's no pointer to your new root.
`root = result.right;` does effectively nothing because you re-assign the parameter and never use it (btw: you should avoid re-assigning parameters, create local variables).
You can modify your `solution1` (after first `if`) and `root` points to your `LinkedList`:

```
if (this.result == null) {
    this.result = new TreeNode(root.val);
    this.pointer = this.result;
} else {
    this.pointer.right = new TreeNode(root.val);
    this.pointer = this.pointer.right;
}
```

`TreeNode pointer;` is a new class member.
`result` is not initialized so it's `null` at first iteration.

Comment: I sort of understand the implementation you've provided but I'm unable to translate it in my program. This is what I have at the moment: https://pastebin.com/raw/62bPEL8F How would I properly insert the ```TreeNode pointer``` to make the "pointer" redirect to the right side? (Please let me know if I should re-clarify my question)

Comment: @KennethChen you must not initialize the class members, especially `result`. Let it `null` at the beginnging so change `TreeNode result =  new TreeNode(-1);` to `TreeNode result;`. In your code `result.right` holds the real root.

Comment: thank you for your response. I went ahead and made the edits that you suggested. Unfortunately, I think I'm still getting the same issue/answer at the end of my program. I attached a copy of it via this link https://pastebin.com/raw/T2Mv8B8v I understand where you're coming from but I'm still getting the same output :(

Comment: @KennethChen I do not see any line of code where you print something. Maybe you print the original tree? I wrote a simple printer for the tree https://pastebin.com/f5n2wWZ5. With `new Printer(n1).print();` (`n1` is the original tree) and `new Printer(s.result).print();` I get what I expect (`s` is my instance of `Solution`). Note that you don't change the original tree but creating a new one!

Comment: ah, I was inputting my answer on the leetcode site (https://leetcode.com/problems/flatten-binary-tree-to-linked-list/) and it was complaining that the expected answer was different from the programmed solution. I'll take a look at the document you've attached